# Exception "Impossible mOptimIntersection count (3)" with OSMDroid when drawing a grid with polylines

Tags: android, kotlin, osmdroid

I am trying to lay a grid over an OSMDroid mapView (like a quad paper). I am doing that with equidistant polylines that get drawn vertically and horizontally in a certain area. There are maybe 200 lines for each orientation.

It actually works, but only with problems:

1. When i scroll the mapview, i get many exceptions of the form:

error dispatchDraw, probably in edit mode
java.lang.RuntimeException: Impossible mOptimIntersection count (3)                                                                                         at org.osmdroid.util.SegmentClipper.clip(SegmentClipper.java:173)                                                                                           at org.osmdroid.util.SegmentClipper.add(SegmentClipper.java:71)                                                                                         at org.osmdroid.views.overlay.LinearRing.clipAndStore(LinearRing.java:389)                                                                                          at org.osmdroid.views.overlay.LinearRing.buildLinePortion(LinearRing.java:279)                                                                                          at org.osmdroid.views.overlay.PolyOverlayWithIW.drawWithLines(PolyOverlayWithIW.java:326)                                                                                           at org.osmdroid.views.overlay.PolyOverlayWithIW.draw(PolyOverlayWithIW.java:242)                                                                                            at org.osmdroid.views.overlay.Overlay.draw(Overlay.java:144)                                                                                            at org.osmdroid.views.overlay.DefaultOverlayManager.onDrawHelper(DefaultOverlayManager.java:179)                                                                                            at org.osmdroid.views.overlay.DefaultOverlayManager.onDraw(DefaultOverlayManager.java:139)                                                                                          at org.osmdroid.views.MapView.dispatchDraw(MapView.java:1253)                                                                                           at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:23242)                                                                                          at android.view.View.draw(View.java:24125)                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4748)                                                                                            at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView.drawChild(FragmentContainerView.kt:235)                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4505)                                                                                         at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView.dispatchDraw(FragmentContainerView.kt:225)                                                                                           at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:23242)                                                                                          at android.view.View.draw(View.java:24125)                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4748)                                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4505)                                                                                         at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:23242)                                                                                          at android.view.View.draw(View.java:24125)                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4748)                                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4505)                                                                                         at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:23242)                                                                                          at android.view.View.draw(View.java:24125)                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4748)                                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4505)                                                                                         at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:23242)                                                                                          at android.view.View.draw(View.java:24125)                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4748)                                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4505)                                                                                         at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:23242)                                                                                          at android.view.View.draw(View.java:24125)                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4748)                                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4505)                                                                                         at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:23242)                                                                                          at android.view.View.draw(View.java:24125)                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4748)                                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4505)                                                                                         at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchDraw(DecorView.java:1531)                                                                                          at android.view.View.draw(View.java:24398)                                                                                          at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:1504)                                                                                          at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:23256)                                                                                          at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:753)                                                                                           at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:759)                                                                                           at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:857)                                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:5501)                                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:5194)                                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:4356)                                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2991)                                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:10665)                                                                                         at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1301)                                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1309)                                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:923)                                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:852)                                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1283)                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)

2023-02-28 19:37:09.760 OsmDroid com.example.affinity                 E     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8741)                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)

2. The second problem: When scrolling there might be missing all vertical or horizontal lines sometimes, when srolling ends.

My code for horiontal lines for example is:

```
    // Horizontale Linien es Rasters zeichnen
    var lat = raster.southwest.latitude
    for (counter in 0 ..raster.n2) {
        val latPolyline = Polyline(mapView)

        latPolyline.getOutlinePaint().setARGB(255, 128, 128, 128)
        latPolyline.outlinePaint.strokeWidth = 1f

        latPolyline.addPoint(GeoPoint(lat, raster.southwest.longitude))
        latPolyline.addPoint(GeoPoint(lat, raster.northeast.longitude))

        mapView.overlays.add(latPolyline)
        latPolylineList.add(latPolyline)

        lat += raster.dy
    }
```

Comment: Just making sure you are aware of existing samples: https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/tree/master/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/gridlines

Comment: Thanks. I cannot use LatLonGridlineOverlay2 as it is, because i need equidistant lines. But i might look like they did it in that class. Though it is pretty complicate. But still i might try to develop my own overlay class like that. Still weird exception above.

Comment: I have succeded in writing my own overlay for my grid now, and i am happy with that. This solution seems to be very stable. Thank you very much again for that idea.